# What is the difference between "I have worked here" and "I have been working here"?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, progressive-aspect, continuous-aspect

What is the difference between the following sentences? When can I use either?

> I have worked here

and

> I have been working here

Comment: Be careful, if you say: I have worked here **since** 2010/leaving school etc. That would mean you are still working "here".

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/8019 (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 4):

'I have worked here' tells me you have, at some stage in your life, worked 'here'.

'I have been working here', suggests you have very recently been, and probably still are, working 'here'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Whilst that may be a valid comment about one or two I have answered, this one seems legitimate to ask. It is a fine point of grammar and not one necessarily easy to resolve with a grammar book. Besides I note you gave a comment yourself. And are we to try and second-guess people's ages?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think there are far worse examples than this one. Have you had an Irish association? Just interested you should say 'they would have commented "whenever" their their question was closed'. Touch of the Irish there!

Comment: Deleted my comments. It's not relevant to the OP's question :)